# C strings giving weird outputs

Tags: c, output

(1)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[5]="hello";
    str[5] = "g";
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**: hello0

Shouldn't this give an error?

(2)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[5]="hello";
    str[3] = "g";
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

**OUPUT**: hel0o
Where is 0 coming in here from?

**Compiler: TDM-GCC-64

Windows 10

Editor: Sublime Text**

Comment: C does not check array bounds. you have to take care of that yourself.

Comment: If your compiler isn't complaining, turn up the warning level (to the max). Besides the out of bounds access the types don't match up

Comment: `char str[5]="hello";` has no string terminator, so passing it to a function that expects one is *undefined behaviour*. C does not **have to** go wrong any more than you **will** get run over crossing a road without looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see multiple mistakes in the given Code.

1- In C syntax trying to assign a double quoted value **returns** a pointer value whose value is the address of the first index of that string.

By doing

```
    str[3] = "g";
```

you are simply asking the compiler to type "g" somewhere on the RAM and return the address of that "g" and assign that value to str[3]. Since C is not type-safe, the compiler auto-casts that pointer to a char, and it usually doesn't end up well.

I think what you really want to do is `str[3] = 'g'` . This way your output would be `helgo` .

2- You shouldn't try to reach  *and definetely not modify* out of the bounds of string. You will end up getting a segmentation fault, or whatever the equivalent is based on your compiler/OS. `str[5]=x` isn't something you want to to unless the size of your str is at least 6.

3- In C, when you use %s for printf or similar functions, it starts showing the values in the screen starting from the pointer you provided (array names are actually constant pointers) until it sees a 0. I don't mean the character 0 ('0') whose actual value is 48. A literal 0. For example, try `str[1]=0` and in your printf it will just show an `h`.

Answer (score 1):

You should have noticed that the value you're assigning to `str[3]` is a type of string, not a character. If you use the `str[3] = 'g'` you should no longer get the error.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[5] = "hello";
    str[3] = 'g'; // "g" != 'g'

    printf("%s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. > Shouldn't this give an error?

The compiler doesn´t detect when you attempt to write beyond the bounds of the array.

But beside that, `str[5] = "g";` gives a warning:

> warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

Since you assign a string to an element of `char`, the behavior and with that the output of is undefined.

2. > Where is 0 coming in here from?

Example:

```
char str[5]="hello";
str[3] = "g";
```

Note that `"g"` is a string, not a character constant like `'g'`. A string always has a terminating null character. This null character is written into the 5th element of `str`.

Beside that as you use the same wrong statement `str[3] = "g";` the behavior is also undefined here.

---

What you need is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[6] = "hello";
    str[3] = 'g';
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
helgo
```